# Java servlet - Forwarding/Redirecting from subpage

Tags: java, servlets, httpresponse

I am working on a project where I have running servlets packaged in a war that listen for requests and populate a foreign div on a separate page. An initial request is made to servlet (a) and if there is data to display, it renders that HTML. If there is NO data, it passes a query string to another servlet to handle the request and then renders a page with options to choose.

I am running Tomcat 6 with Windows Server 2008.

But I run into two problems:

1. When I use redirect, I get no response from the servlet being
   redirected to. I have some javascript alerts up that are never called by the (b)
   servlet. I AM using relative paths and confirm the link is
   correct in logs.
2. When I copy that link in step 1 in a new window, I see
   the results. Just not when it's embedded in another page that makes
   the request. Why would that be? Is it possibly a limitation from the host page and not being able to render the response?
3. When I use a forward, I see the servlet response,
   but then a new window opens. Thus taking the person away from the
   original page. This would be great if the results render in the same page.

What's the best practice to assure that I can "redirect" from an initial servlet call to another servlet using the response object from that first servlet?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a foreign div"? Your response has to be to the same client that made the request. Also, servlets (which run on the server) cannot call Javascript (which runs on the browser.

Comment: Basically we have a website, www.isendrequests.com, that makes a call in JS on load to my servlet and then renders a div on the page with the HTML I send back in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A redirect returns a HTTP 302 response with the new URL in `Location` header which the client needs to deal with. Basically, your JS code must check the response status code if it's 302 and then extract the `Location` header and then re-send a new request on it. Repeat this until the response status code is 200.

That it works when pasting the URL in browser's address bar is because the browser already knows how to deal with 3nn responses properly. If you open up the network traffic tracker in browser's webdeveloper toolset, then you'll see that a second GET request is been fired on the new URL.

Another way, if the servlets run in the same container, is to just use `RequestDispatcher#forward()` instead of `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC - I can let the server handle the forwarding using RequestDispatcher, but it renders a completely different page. Any ideas on how to get the forward to render the same page that made the call?

Comment: Apparently the forwarding servlet is still writing to the response while it should not do. Are you sure that you're returning properly after the forward or that you've put the remaining of the code in an `else`?